# Make USB Bootable From Mac OS 10.8.4

Tags: mac, boot

I have an older Lenovo computer that I'm trying to get to boot to a USB drive.

However I only have a Mac to make this bootable USB Drive.

I'm trying to boot the Windows installation but that is not working.

What is the recommended way to create a bootable USB drive, even if it only boots into a boot manager?

Comment: Which Windows version?  Do you have a Disc or an ISO?  What have you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a bootable USB Windows OS using Mac OS X](http://superuser.com/questions/421402/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-windows-os-using-mac-os-x)