# How can I set boot flags on a USB device from OS X El Capitan?

Tags: windows, macos

I am trying to make a Windows 10 bootable usb from OS X El Capitan. I have read that I need to set the "msftdata" flag on the device. How would I do this? I can only find solutions using gParted on linux.

Comment: see http://superuser.com/questions/421402/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-windows-os-using-mac-os-x re:unetbootin